# Something is wrong with sql query

Tags: php, mysql

Please check this code and let me know if there is any mistakes in it.

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $shop_item);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$item_sql = "SELECT * FROM shop-items";
mysqli_query($conn, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8;');
$result_item = mysqli_query($conn, $item_sql);

echo var_dump($result_item); //returns: bool(false)
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_item) > 0) { // doesn't execute. the error is "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean";
```

Comment: Definitely `shop-items` considered like `shop minus items`

Comment: Thanks. I tried the phpmyadmin query which is "SELECT * FROM `shop-items`" and it performed the job.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned `shop-items` is treated by mysql as `shop minus items`.
If your table name is really `shop-items` - you should use backticks to escape it:

```
$item_sql = "SELECT * FROM `shop-items`";
```

And for checking errors you can use `mysqli_error()` function:

```
$err = mysqli_error($conn);
echo $err;
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be better to use structure similar to this:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'your_database');
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM shop-items";

if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {    
    // actions in case of success    
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: This will still cause an error.

Comment: well the error definitely not due to php structure. what kind of mysql error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with the dash. Have you tried

```
SELECT * FROM `shop-items`
```

Comment: Yes. thanks. the correct query was "SELECT * FROM `shop-items`".

Answer (score 1):

I would try and use the following code for all my queries from PHP to you database because as someone mentioned before with what you're using errors can occur from not syntax:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "DB");

/* Check conection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conection error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM shop-items";

if ($stmt= $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute the query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Bind the results to variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2); //as many variables as columns the query will return

    /* obtener los valores */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //do something with the results
    }

    /* close the query */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close the DB connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Hope this helps!!